# How Can I Return a Variable Pointer with a value of NULL

Tags: c++

I am doing a project that involves traversing a linked list of Nodes, and in order to do so I need to be able to check if Node.next() has a value or if it is NULL. Currently I am using

```
if (node->GetNext()==NULL){
  //do stuff
}
```

but I get a segmentation fault for this.

```cpp
//Funcion in LinkedList class

void LinkedList::InsertEnd(Node* newNode){
  if (m_head==NULL){
    m_head=newNode;
    cout << "Node set as m_head\n";
  }else{
    Node* temp = m_head;
    int i=1;

    do{
      temp=temp->GetNext();
    }while(temp->GetNext()==NULL);

    temp->SetNext(newNode);
    cout << "Node added at index" << i << endl;
  }
  cout << "Node inserted successfully\n\n";
}


//Node class

Node::Node(){
  m_next = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(bool value){
  m_value = value;
  m_next = nullptr;
}

void Node::ReplaceValue(){
  m_value = !m_value;
}

void Node::SetNext(Node* next){
  m_next = next;
}

Node* Node::GetNext(){
  return m_next;
}
bool Node::GetValue(){
  return m_value;
}

Node::~Node(){
}
```

`InsertEnd` should add `newNode` to the end of the current Linked List, but instead when I call `GetNext` within the node class I get this segmentation fault

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401278 in Node::GetNext (this=0x0) at Node.cpp:21
21        return m_next;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `GetNext` like that. The problem came when you're trying to call a method from a null pointer, because of `do while`. Change it from

```
do{
    temp=temp->GetNext();
}while(temp->GetNext()==NULL);
```

to

```
while (temp->GetNext() != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->GetNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do checking simply do -

```
while(temp->next != NULL)
{
  //do stuff
}
```